# Optimized performance testing for PostgreSQL views

Tags: postgresql, performance-testing

I have 12 different views that I want to run with different criteria and save the results (time it took to return the results and number of records, by each criteria).

I'm now doing this by running each view with a criteria, and writing those results in a table, but that is very slow and I was thinking that there could be a better way. Something that I will be able to run on a regular basis.

Do you have any proposals?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) like [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) (or any other tool which is capable of talking to PostgreSQL via [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity)/[JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)/whatever protocol is used by the upstream system) to run your queries automatically and/or even in multithreaded manner.

If you add [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to use [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to run your queries and Listeners to monitor your results.

You can also connect JMeter with [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) and use [performance plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/) to observe trend charts and be notified in case of performance degradation.